# How many winners can a challenge have?

Tags: discussion, policy, winning-criteria

I'm currently writing a challenge which forces people to work in pairs to participate in the challenge. However, this leads to the question, who wins in the pair?

I'm thinking about (ideally) having a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) (don't boo until after reading the challenge), where a pair's score is the sum of their upvotes minus the sum of their downvotes. But this would lead to two people winning the challenge. Is this OK, or can only one person win a challenge (ignoring ties)?

Comment: You can bounty.

Comment: SE dev team won't specialize the "accepted" for particular site, so we can just agree that they won, for example with a notice in the question "Congratulation to \@userA and \@userB who won the challenge"...

Comment: @user202729 It's not about giving a reward to multiple winners (such as bountying or accepting), it's about our policy on challenges where there isn't a single winner.

Comment: We already have plenty of golf challenges where the challenger specifies that the winner**s** are the shortest solutions in each language.

Comment: The accept checkmark can pretty much go to whichever entry you want it to. E.g. you can pick one that was sufficiently impressive, even if it wasn't the *absolute* winner (for example, a Jelly entry is 18 bytes, but someone managed to do the challenge in, say, *Excel Macros* or *Minecraft redstone logic* and its just so good that even though it has more bytes, its worth the extra 15 rep). The accept mark on many challenges has been pretty subjective for a while.

Comment: @Draco18s That is decidedly false. The check mark (if used, which isn't preferable) should be used to accept the winner, rather than the most impressive. An 18 byte Jelly answer should be accepted over a 230 byte Java answer, irregardless of how impressive they are.

Answer (score 2):

## The rules are specified in the challenges itself

As long as it is programming puzzle, and it have objective winning criteria, any rules are fine. That includes allow multiple users to win.

---

I don't see any problem with this, except that it may changes how PPCG users work. However there are already a lot of answers on this site involves teamwork (the most famous one is the Tetris GoL challenge), so it should be normal.